# Disable Copy/Paste/Cut in WPF VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am trying to disable Copy/Paste/Cut feature in textbox in WPF VB.NET

This code works fine :

```
     Private Sub textbox_PreviewExecuted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)
    If e.Command Is ApplicationCommands.Copy OrElse e.Command Is ApplicationCommands.Cut OrElse e.Command Is ApplicationCommands.Paste Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

But disabling CTRL+C/CTRL+V using this code doesn't work :

```
  DataObject.AddPastingHandler(control, AddressOf Me.OnCancelCommand)
  DataObject.AddCopyingHandler(control, AddressOf Me.OnCancelCommand)

 private void OnCancelCommand(Object sender, DataObjectEventArgs e)
e.CancelCommand()
```

How to make the 2nd code work ?

Comment: Your code is a bit incomplete and confusing. Also, your XAML textbox is missing, which might be important somehow.

Comment: If person can select a text, can take that text with drug and drop anyway, you might want to disable selection itself

Answer (score 0):

You can re-bind the commands. Here is a C# version, VB.Net should be similar

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute"/>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute"/>
    </TextBox.CommandBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Handler:

```
private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = false;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Consider adding `ApplicationCommands.Cut` to the party, unless you have different plans for it.